# Without using PHP copy function, move file from one folder to another

Tags: php, file-io

How can we move the one file from one folder to another folder without copy function in PHP.
In php copy function used to copy the file from one folder to another folder. But in my case I don't use copy function for move the file from folder to another folder.

Comment: If you don't want to use the built-in functions; read the file from source, write to destination, delete from source if required

Comment: Note that copy and move are different

Answer (score 2):

You can try and make use of php rename function. It will move the file if a new directory was specified in the new `move to` filename. Just ensure that the permission are correct when moving and creating new folders and files.

```
rename("path1/file.txt", "path2/file.txt");
```

[**PHP RENAME**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

> Attempts to rename oldname to newname, moving it between directories
>   if necessary. If newname exists, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want use PHP `copy()` function for some reason, you can do this like:

```
system('cp /path/to/src_file /path/to/dst_file');
```

for *nix systems, and

```
system('copy /path/to/src_file /path/to/dst_file');
```

for Windows

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using rename().
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
rename('/dir1/old_dir/old_name.txt','/dir1/new_dir/zzz_name.bak');
```